# Preventing the Jasmine spy to listen improper messages

Tags: jasmine

How can I tell the Jasmine spy to only listen the messages I tell it to expect and ignore any others?

For example:

**Example Group**

```
describe 'View', ->
  describe 'render', ->
    beforeEach ->
      @view    = new View
      @view.el = jasmine.createSpyObj 'el', ['append']
      @view.render()

    it 'appends the first entry to the list', ->
      expect(@view.el.append).toHaveBeenCalledWith '<li>First</li>'

    it 'appends the second entry to the list', ->
      expect(@view.el.append).toHaveBeenCalledWith '<li>Second</li>'
```

**Implementation**

```
class View
  render: ->
    @el.append '<li>First</li>', '<li>Second</li>'
```

**Output**

```
View
  render
    appends the first entry to the list
      Expected spy el.append to have been called \
        with [ '<li>First</li>' ] but was called \
        with [ [ '<li>First</li>', '<li>Second</li>' ] ]

    appends the second entry to the list
      Expected spy el.append to have been called \
        with [ '<li>Second</li>' ] but was called \
        with [ [ '<li>First</li>', '<li>Second</li>' ] ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options:

**1.** Using the [`argsForCall`](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/jsdoc/symbols/jasmine.Spy.html#argsForCall) spy property

```
it 'appends the first entry to the list', ->
   expect(@view.el.append.argsForCall[0]).toContain '<li>First</li>'
```

**2.** Using the `args` property of the [`mostRecentCall`](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/jsdoc/symbols/jasmine.Spy.html#mostRecentCall) object

```
it 'appends the first entry to the list', ->
   expect(@view.el.append.mostRecentCall.args).toContain '<li>First</li>'
```

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, you can't prevent the spy from listening. The spy will listen to all function calls and save them. But you can excess every single call by using [argsForCall](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/jsdoc/symbols/jasmine.Spy.html#argsForCall).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, **Andreas**. I've wrote about `argsForCall` in my answer. If you are familiar with the RSpec Ruby BDD framework, you probably know that it defines the [`as_null_object`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-6/docs/method-stubs/as-null-object) method for doubles. These doubles will ignore any other messages which you didn't stub and the doubles won't raise any exceptions when they receive these messages. I thought that Jasmine has the similar functionality, something like `jasmine.createSpyObj('Object', ['method']).as_null_object()`.